#include <unistd.h> doesn't work in visual studio code in Windows
I tried to include this library to allow fork(), exec() and pipe() commands. Unfortunately, this error message is displayed:

#inclusion errors detected. Update the inclusion path. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\franc\OneDrive\Desktop\ProjCrypto\UniProject_Cryptography2024\main.cpp).

I already tried to edit the JSON file in the .vscode folder inside my project, and asked ChatGPT.
Should I use some command on the terminal or something else? I thought even on WSL, but I don't know how to use it properly. Even because I've already installed a C compiler.

That header file and the functions you mention are for POSIX (i.e. Unix) systems, like Linux or macOS. They are not available for Windows, which have its own set of corresponding functions.

If the toolchain is MSVC, nothing else is expected. That header belongs to POSIX compliant platforms. On windows platforms, you'd need the linux subsystem with cygwin or mingw toolchain.

Now I have installed mingw. However, I still have the same error as before. when I open visual code the library remains unavailable. What can I do?

Use a framework that is portable across multiple operating systems.
